# How can I save video from webcam?

Tags: video, save, julia

I want to save video from webcam. What I need to add?
I tried save and load , but it didn't work.

```
import Makie
import VideoIO

io = VideoIO.open("rtsp://......@.....")
f = VideoIO.openvideo(io)

img = read(f)
scene = Makie.Scene(resolution = size(img)) 
makieimg = Makie.image!(scene, img, show_axis = false, scale_plot = false)[end] 
Makie.rotate!(scene, -0.5pi)
display(scene)

while !eof(f)
read!(f, img)
makieimg[1] = img
sleep(0.01)
end
```